# Regex to extract the string

Tags: python, regex

I need help with regex to get the following out of the string

```
dal001.caxxxxx.test.com. ---> caxxxxx.test.com
caxxxx.test.com -----> caxxxx.test.com
```

So basically in the first example, I don't want `dal001` or anything that starts with 3 letters and 3 digits and want the rest of the string if it starts with only `ca`.

In second example I want the whole string that starts only with `ca`.

So far I have tried `(^[a-z]{3}[\d]+\.)?(ca.*)` but it doesn't work when the string is
`dal001.mycaxxxx.test.com`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does `ca.*$` work for you?

Comment: Turn the first group into a non-capturing one, `^(?:[a-z]{3}\d{3}\.)?(ca.*)`, the value will be in Group 1. See https://regex101.com/r/mL8mkG/1 and https://ideone.com/hS6lz5

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it worked really well. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
^(?:[a-z]{3}\d{3}\.)?(ca.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mL8mkG/1). To make it case insensitive, compile with `re.I` (`re.search(rx, s, re.I)`, see below).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[a-z]{3}\d{3}\.)?` - an optional sequence of 3 letters and then 3 digits and a `.`
- `(ca.*)` - Group 1: `ca` and the rest of the string.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/hS6lz5):

```py
import re
rx = r"^(?:[a-z]{3}\d{3}\.)?(ca.*)"
strs = ["dal001.caxxxxx.test.com","caxxxx.test.com"]
for s in strs:
  m = re.search(rx, s)
  if m:
    print( m.group(1) )
```

Comment: This is working really well. Thank you so much.

Comment: The only problem is when there is a non matching string it fails
```
In [13]: re.search(r"^(?:[a-z]{3}\d{3}\.)?(ca.*)",'10.9.65.35').group(1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-0e801dcaecbc> in <module>()
----> 1 re.search(r"^(?:[a-z]{3}\d{3}\.)?(ca.*)",'10.9.65.35').group(1)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```
Is there a way to ignore if the string doesn't match without using try ?

Comment: @developthou **Always** check if there is a match before accessing `.group()`s. I have shown how in the answer, you are not using my code.

Comment: I am using the list comprehension
 return [re.search(r"^(?:[a-z]{3}\d{3}\.)?(ca.*)",host).group(1) for host in hosts]

which doesn't work when there is no match

Comment: I think in this case is not to use list comprehension I believe

Comment: @developthou What Python version are you targeting?

Comment: I am using python 2.7

Comment: @developthou Aha, so you can't use the walrus operator there, it was only introduced in Python 3.8.

Comment: I got rid of list comprehension and works now. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) like so:

```
import re
strs = ['dal001.caxxxxx.test.com', 'caxxxx.test.com']

for s in strs:
    s = re.sub(r'^[A-Za-z]{3}\d{3}[.]', '', s)
    print(s)
# caxxxxx.test.com
# caxxxx.test.com
```

Comment: Thank you but this will not extract the string if it only matches **ca**

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `re`:

```
import re
my_strings = ['dal001.caxxxxx.test.com', 'caxxxxx.test.com']
my_regex = r'^(?:[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}\.)?(ca.*)'
compiled_regex = re.compile(r)
for a_string in my_strings:
    if compiled_regex.match(a_string):
        compiled_regex.sub(r'\1', a_string)
```

`my_regex` matches a string that starts (`^` anchors to the start of the string) with `[3 letters][3 digits][a .]`, but only optionally, and using a non-capturing group (the `(?:)` will not get a numbered reference to use in `sub`). In either case, it must then contain `ca` followed by anything, and this part is used as the replacement in the call to `re.sub`. `re.compile` is used to make it a bit faster, in case you have many strings to match.

Note on `re.compile`:
Some answers don't bother pre-compiling the regex before the loop. They have made a trade: removing a single line of code, at the cost of *re-compiling the regex implicitly on every iteration*. If you will use a regex in a loop body, you should always compile it first. Doing so can have a **major** effect on the speed of a program, and there is no added cost even when the number of iterations is small. [Here is a comparison](https://github.com/zfortier/re_compile_or_not/blob/master/result) of compiled vs. non-compiled versions of [the same loop using the same regex](https://github.com/zfortier/re_compile_or_not/blob/49f599aaf7b897db421f4e896a06786775066fe1/testre.py#L13-L28) for different numbers of loop iterations and number of trials. Judge for yourself.